# CI TeamCity for android can not build .apk file for project with library and default build.xml

Tags: android, teamcity

I have a project that has lib as not a .jar but as an android library project. So I want to include CI in my workflow. I set up the server that successfully build project but doesn't generate .apk file. I had followed the adbice and set up "debug" as target property on one of the step in TeamCity wizard and it seems server to start make attempts to build .apk but it throw an exception such as:

```
../Android_library resolve to a path with no project.properties file for project C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\df2ac20d908e5f7f
```

I have default eclipse build.xml file for both apps are generate via commands:

```
android update project -p ./ -t 6 -s (for library)
android update project -p ./ -t 6 -l ../Android_library -s (for main project)
```

I am able to build this project locally and the command below finish words with Vuild Succesfully:

```
ant debug clean
```

But when I run the CI the build is failed.

All projects lays in the same root directory. 
VCS root is the path to my main project
Default properties looks contains those rows:

```
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:14
android.library.reference.1=../Android_library

target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:14
android.library=true
```

So I'm stuck. Do you know where the issue can be? All help will be appreciated.

build.xml for project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="LoginActivity" default="help">

<!-- The local.properties file is created and updated by the 'android' tool.
     It contains the path to the SDK. It should *NOT* be checked into
     Version Control Systems. -->
<property file="local.properties" />

<!-- The ant.properties file can be created by you. It is only edited by the
     'android' tool to add properties to it.
     This is the place to change some Ant specific build properties.
     Here are some properties you may want to change/update:

     source.dir
         The name of the source directory. Default is 'src'.
     out.dir
         The name of the output directory. Default is 'bin'.

     For other overridable properties, look at the beginning of the rules
     files in the SDK, at tools/ant/build.xml

     Properties related to the SDK location or the project target should
     be updated using the 'android' tool with the 'update' action.

     This file is an integral part of the build system for your
     application and should be checked into Version Control Systems.

     -->
<property file="ant.properties" />

<!-- if sdk.dir was not set from one of the property file, then
     get it from the ANDROID_HOME env var.
     This must be done before we load project.properties since
     the proguard config can use sdk.dir -->
<property environment="env" />
<condition property="sdk.dir" value="${env.ANDROID_HOME}">
    <isset property="env.ANDROID_HOME" />
</condition>

<!-- The project.properties file is created and updated by the 'android'
     tool, as well as ADT.

     This contains project specific properties such as project target, and library
     dependencies. Lower level build properties are stored in ant.properties
     (or in .classpath for Eclipse projects).

     This file is an integral part of the build system for your
     application and should be checked into Version Control Systems. -->
<loadproperties srcFile="project.properties" />

<!-- quick check on sdk.dir -->
<fail
        message="sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project' or to inject it through the ANDROID_HOME environment variable."
        unless="sdk.dir"
/>

<!--
    Import per project custom build rules if present at the root of the project.
    This is the place to put custom intermediary targets such as:
        -pre-build
        -pre-compile
        -post-compile (This is typically used for code obfuscation.
                       Compiled code location: ${out.classes.absolute.dir}
                       If this is not done in place, override ${out.dex.input.absolute.dir})
        -post-package
        -post-build
        -pre-clean
-->
<import file="custom_rules.xml" optional="true" />

<!-- Import the actual build file.

     To customize existing targets, there are two options:
     - Customize only one target:
         - copy/paste the target into this file, *before* the
           <import> task.
         - customize it to your needs.
     - Customize the whole content of build.xml
         - copy/paste the content of the rules files (minus the top node)
           into this file, replacing the <import> task.
         - customize to your needs.

     ***********************
     ****** IMPORTANT ******
     ***********************
     In all cases you must update the value of version-tag below to read 'custom' instead of an integer,
     in order to avoid having your file be overridden by tools such as "android update project"
-->
<!-- version-tag: 1 -->
<import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />
</project>
```

build.xml for library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="MainActivity" default="help">

<!-- The local.properties file is created and updated by the 'android' tool.
     It contains the path to the SDK. It should *NOT* be checked into
     Version Control Systems. -->
<property file="local.properties" />

<!-- The ant.properties file can be created by you. It is only edited by the
     'android' tool to add properties to it.
     This is the place to change some Ant specific build properties.
     Here are some properties you may want to change/update:

     source.dir
         The name of the source directory. Default is 'src'.
     out.dir
         The name of the output directory. Default is 'bin'.

     For other overridable properties, look at the beginning of the rules
     files in the SDK, at tools/ant/build.xml

     Properties related to the SDK location or the project target should
     be updated using the 'android' tool with the 'update' action.

     This file is an integral part of the build system for your
     application and should be checked into Version Control Systems.

     -->
<property file="ant.properties" />

<!-- if sdk.dir was not set from one of the property file, then
     get it from the ANDROID_HOME env var.
     This must be done before we load project.properties since
     the proguard config can use sdk.dir -->
<property environment="env" />
<condition property="sdk.dir" value="${env.ANDROID_HOME}">
    <isset property="env.ANDROID_HOME" />
</condition>

<!-- The project.properties file is created and updated by the 'android'
     tool, as well as ADT.

     This contains project specific properties such as project target, and library
     dependencies. Lower level build properties are stored in ant.properties
     (or in .classpath for Eclipse projects).

     This file is an integral part of the build system for your
     application and should be checked into Version Control Systems. -->
<loadproperties srcFile="project.properties" />

<!-- quick check on sdk.dir -->
<fail
        message="sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project' or to inject it through the ANDROID_HOME environment variable."
        unless="sdk.dir"
/>

<!--
    Import per project custom build rules if present at the root of the project.
    This is the place to put custom intermediary targets such as:
        -pre-build
        -pre-compile
        -post-compile (This is typically used for code obfuscation.
                       Compiled code location: ${out.classes.absolute.dir}
                       If this is not done in place, override ${out.dex.input.absolute.dir})
        -post-package
        -post-build
        -pre-clean
-->
<import file="custom_rules.xml" optional="true" />

<!-- Import the actual build file.

     To customize existing targets, there are two options:
     - Customize only one target:
         - copy/paste the target into this file, *before* the
           <import> task.
         - customize it to your needs.
     - Customize the whole content of build.xml
         - copy/paste the content of the rules files (minus the top node)
           into this file, replacing the <import> task.
         - customize to your needs.

     ***********************
     ****** IMPORTANT ******
     ***********************
     In all cases you must update the value of version-tag below to read 'custom' instead of an integer,
     in order to avoid having your file be overridden by tools such as "android update project"
-->
<!-- version-tag: 1 -->
<import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolve my issue. The problem was in path that input in the CI build stem. It is important to define your VCS path as path too the folder that contains both projects but path to the build set up as /build.xml